# creating method signals to automatically fire up on an event in python

Tags: python

I don't honestly know if such thing exists or not, but I tried to do some research and ended up getting confused with something called d-Bus and not sure if that's what am looking for here,

```
class BigClass(Object):
  def Foo(self):
     print 'calling foo'

  def Logger(self):
     print 'foo has been called'

a = BigClass()
a.foo()
```

what am trying to do here is invoke Logger() method when foo() is being called. I want to create some sort of a event/signal where it will fire up logger() when specific methods are called in my class or all methods.

Comment: You probably want 'object' and 'foo', not 'Object' and 'Foo'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know your particular situation, but there is a good signal/callback lib called `dispatch`: http://pydispatcher.sourceforge.net/

But i prefer using Django dispatcher which was created based on PyDispatcher, but [signal creation is more intuitive](https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/Signals): https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/dispatch/dispatcher.py

> what am trying to do here is invoke Logger() method when foo() is
>   being called. I want to create some sort of a event/signal where it
>   will fire up logger() when specific methods are called in my class or
>   all methods.

Why don't you then call `Logger` method manually from `foo` method? Or better make a decorator to use it like:

```
class BigClass(Object):

  def Logger(self):
     print 'foo has been called'

  @log(Logger)
  def Foo(self):
     print 'calling foo'


a = BigClass()
a.foo()
```

Answer (score 0):

While an explicit logging call (or logging decorator, as warwaruk suggests) is the most straightforward approach, it is possible to automate logging, if you're willing to play a naming trick such as having the logical `foo` method be implemented by `Foo`. Python is case-sensitive, so those are separate and distinct. Then implement a `__getattr__` method, like so:

```
class AutoLogger(object):

    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        try:
            return self.__class__.__dict__[attr]
        except KeyError:
            func = self.__class__.__dict__[attr.capitalize()]
            return lambda *args, **kwargs: self.log_call(attr, func, *args, **kwargs)

    def log_call(self, func_name, func, *args, **kwargs):
        func(self, *args, **kwargs)
        print func_name, 'has been called (handled by', func_name.capitalize() + ')'

class BigAutoLoggerClass(AutoLogger):
    def Foo(self):
        print 'calling Foo'


b = BigAutoLoggerClass()
b.Foo()
print "---"
b.foo()
```

This yields:

```
calling Foo
---
calling Foo
foo has been called (handled by Foo)
```

`bar` would similarly be implemented by `Bar`, and so on.

If you don't like this naming slight-of-hand, logging can also be automated via the `sys.settrace()` function. That, however, adds a lot of run-time overhead and is really only suited for debugging or situations where low(ish) performance is okay.